# What cable do I need for this port?

Tags: port, vga, adapter

I have tried to plug a monitor to a Dell computer into the VGA slot and I have received this message: `This computer has an add-in graphics card, but the monitor is plugged into the integrated video connector. To attach the monitor cable to the add-in graphics card...`

After a quick search, it seems I need an adapter that I do not have (not a DVI one, I have already tried) maybe for this slot but I do not know what this port is for:

[image]

Comment: The message actually states what your problem is. You should use DVI cable. The other one is legacy, I think

Comment: Not legacy, it is DMS-59  See( [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59)).

Comment: @Ashtray: I have already tried to plug a DVI one and even a DVI to VGA adaptator and it just does not fit into this slot.(And yes I have already numerous DVI cable at work :D)

Comment: You need to plug in a DMS-59 cable. See the link I posted 2 hours ago. The card should have come with either one or two of these cables: 1) DMS-59 to dual analog VGA. 2) DMS-59 to dual DVI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a "dual DVI" port.

You need an adapter that splits it into two separate DVI or VGA adapters.  Be careful, honestly this is a poor design and can put stress on the graphics card if you aren't careful where you lead the cable.

Below is the DVI version but there's a dual DVI to VGA version as well.

[image]

The other port is an [7-pin variation of the S-Video port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-video#7-pin_mini-DIN).

Regarding your message, many business (GX, Optiplex) Dell desktops won't let you use the integrated VGA with the graphics card together.  Not sure why this is (not enough PCIe lanes to support both in the chipset maybe?)